# Check for changes to a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

is there a way to get database checksum using system SQL Server functions?

Or other way to quickly figure out if there are any changes in database?

I do not want to use any specific database analysis software for this.

I look for any changes in database (schema/object changes, data changes).

I use SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Are you talking schema/object changes or data changes, or both?

Comment: What version of Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Why dont you want to use any specific database analysis software?

Comment: I don't want to use analysis software because I will use this function from code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find the information in the transaction log...

Use

```
DBCC LOG(<database name>[,{0|1|2|3|4}])
```

0 - Basic Log Information (default)

1 - Lengthy Info

2 - Very Length Info

3 - Detailed

4 - Full

Example:

```
DBCC log (MY_DB, 4)
```

The result is somewhat cryptic and is better used with a third-party tool thought...

Credits: http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/KnowHow/ViewLog.htm

EDIT:

You might try

```
Select * from ::fn_dblog(null, null)
```

This page contains some usefull information about the results returned by the functions...
http://www.novicksoftware.com/udfofweek/Vol1/T-SQL-UDF-Volume-1-Number-27-fn_dblog.htm

Keep in mind, that those procedures are not for the public and therefore not easy to understand. The other possibility is to add triggers on all tables. But that is on the otherhand a lot of work.

Comment: And how can I analyze this result? It is not possible to calculate rows from DBCC log

Comment: Well the problem here is that you don't want to use third party tools and you were asking for system functions. That's it.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That what I really want. It would be great if something like this for database would exist CHECKSUM_AGG http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36/check-for-changes-to-a-sql-table

Answer (score 1):

One approach to record/log schema changes is to use [DDL triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-ddl-triggers-in-sql-server-2005-to-capture-schema-changes) as of SQL Server 2005.

You can set them up on a database to fire on specific types of schema changes (e.g. CREATE_PROCEDURE, ALTER_PROCEDURE) and then maintain whatever log you want to.

Answer (score 1):

By "changes" I had a similar problem but not changes to the data, rather changes to the schema. I created the following function to generate a checksum of the whole database schema based on INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Expand to additional information schema tables if your system uses them, this is enough for my usage.

I've used this to create a daily alert to notify me of any changes to our production database, so it's become easy to police unplanned/unauthorised changes by other team members. Simply store the checksum, and then run the function and compare to the stored value. If different, then someone has changed something.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].GetDbSchemaChecksum 
(   
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @retVal int
    set @retVal = 
    (
    SELECT 
        CHECKSUM_AGG(T.Chk) DbSchemaChecksum
    FROM
        (
        select checksum(TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE) Chk from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        union all
        select checksum(TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_DEFAULT, IS_NULLABLE, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE, DATETIME_PRECISION) Chk from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        union all
        select checksum(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, CONSTRAINT_NAME, UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG, UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME, MATCH_OPTION, UPDATE_RULE, DELETE_RULE) Chk from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
        union all
        select checksum(CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_TYPE, IS_DEFERRABLE, INITIALLY_DEFERRED) Chk from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
        union all
        select checksum(TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, CONSTRAINT_NAME) Chk from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE
        union all
        select checksum(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION) Chk from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
        union all
        select checksum(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, CONSTRAINT_NAME, CHECK_CLAUSE) Chk from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS 
        union all
        select checksum(TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, VIEW_DEFINITION, CHECK_OPTION, IS_UPDATABLE) Chk from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
        union all
        select checksum(VIEW_SCHEMA, VIEW_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME) Chk from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
        union all
        select checksum(SPECIFIC_SCHEMA, SPECIFIC_NAME, ROUTINE_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_TYPE, ROUTINE_DEFINITION) Chk from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
        union all
        select checksum(SPECIFIC_SCHEMA, SPECIFIC_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, PARAMETER_MODE, IS_RESULT, AS_LOCATOR, PARAMETER_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) Chk from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
        ) AS T
    )

    return @retVal

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes in the form of updates to tables in the form of updates/insertions/deletions can be tracked by use of a trigger which would update the timestamp in a master table. We have to maintain a table containing the name of tables and last updated time. Any change in the individual table would update this table in the corresponding row!

Schema changes can also be handled by way of triggers which would update the table of tables. May be in you case, we can have additional column(s) with BOOL data type that would specify if the change was in schema or the data.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that SQL Server 2008+ Enterprise edition has a feature called [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx)

This will capture any insert, updates, deletes on the database. Unfortunately I don't have Enterprise edition to test this out. I'll add links here so that it will be of help to someone in the future.

[Enable/Disable Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627369.aspx)

[Good writeup on how to use this feature](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-%28cdc%29-in-sql-server-2008/)

EDIT:
For the Standard Edition there is [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx).

Related Questions:
[Auditing SQL Server data changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793643/auditing-sql-server-data-changes)