# What conditions cause CHECKSUM_AGG to return 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, checksum

It seems that there are a number of conditions that cause `CHECKSUM_AGG` to return 0 that I wouldn't have expected. I've only been able to find one discussed, which is that duplicate values will cause it. That can be solved via a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`.

I've also found a couple more scenarios that make less sense to me. One was provided by my boss and one I found [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/3e0c17ac-fc6b-469d-9542-940b0752fdf4). These I don't know how to explain. Here is some SQL that demonstrates the scenarios:

```
SELECT
    CHECKSUM_AGG(T.Number) AS ChecksumAgggregate
FROM
(
    VALUES
        (2)
        , (3)
        , (4)
        , (5)
)AS T(Number)

DECLARE @t TABLE 
(
    Category VARCHAR(15),
    Value VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT @t 
(
    Category
    , Value
)
VALUES 
    ('OneCharacter','a')
    ,('OneCharacter','b')
    ,('OneCharacter','c')
    ,('OneCharacter','d')

    ,('TwoCharacters','aa')
    ,('TwoCharacters','bb')
    ,('TwoCharacters','cc')
    ,('TwoCharacters','dd')

    ,('ThreeCharacters','aaa')
    ,('ThreeCharacters','bbb')
    ,('ThreeCharacters','ccc')
    ,('ThreeCharacters','ddd')

    ,('SixCharacters','aaaaaa')
    ,('SixCharacters','bbbbbb')
    ,('SixCharacters','cccccc')
    ,('SixCharacters','dddddd')

    ,('AllValues','a')
    ,('AllValues','b')
    ,('AllValues','c')
    ,('AllValues','d')
    ,('AllValues','aa')
    ,('AllValues','bb')
    ,('AllValues','cc')
    ,('AllValues','dd')
    ,('AllValues','aaa')
    ,('AllValues','bbb')
    ,('AllValues','ccc')
    ,('AllValues','ddd')
    ,('AllValues','aaaaaa')
    ,('AllValues','bbbbbb')
    ,('AllValues','cccccc')
    ,('AllValues','dddddd')

select 
    Category, CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM(Value)) 
from @t 
group by Category

select Category, Value, CHECKSUM(Value) ValueChecksum
from @t
```

It's nothing but 0's in these examples from `CHECKSUM_AGG` from these queries. The last query shows that none of the `CHECKSUM` values that are getting input into the `CHECKSUM_AGG` call are duplicated.

I'm hoping that whatever answer describes what causes `CHECKSUM_AGG` to return 0 will explain these situations as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if, for example, there is an even number of rows, or if the values sum up to certain values (e.g. 14). These both yield 0:

```
SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(N)
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(4)) AS T(N);

SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(N)
FROM (VALUES (2),(3),(4),(5)) AS T(N);
```

But these do not:

```
SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(N)
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) AS T(N);

SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(N)
FROM (VALUES (2),(3),(4),(6)) AS T(N);
```

14 may just be a coincidence (and it doesn't happen for that value across 6 rows), I mention it only because it's the only pattern I noticed here. I don't know that any of these cases are documented.

Also you are aware that [`CHECKSUM_AGG` is officially documented as being not reliable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188920%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), i.e. it may not accurately reflect a data change, right? The doc doesn't go into details on this, it just states that sometimes it won't tell you there's been a change even if there has. (The actual wording is "However, there is a small chance that the checksum will not change.")

Anyway [Michael Swart seems to have discovered that `CHECKSUM_AGG` is just `XOR`](http://michaeljswart.com/2009/02/checksum_agg-a-very-nifty-function/) (here is his proof):

```
CREATE TABLE #f(a FLOAT);
GO

INSERT #f VALUES (RAND());
GO 20

DECLARE @i INT = 0;
SELECT @i = @i ^ CHECKSUM(a) FROM #f;
SELECT @i, CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM(a)) FROM #f;
GO

DROP TABLE #f;
GO
```

As he goes on to explain, this can lead to misleading results when the range of values is very small, since the odds of generating a reliable checksum diminishes rapidly.

Comment: CHECKSUM for INT just returns the same value unaltered. This explains why you noticed a pattern with few small integers: They are just xor'ed as is.

Comment: @usr rIght, I think that's part of the reason Michael's example uses FLOAT instead of INT (and the results are the same whether you have 20 rows or 200,000 rows).

Comment: I just took my example and did that XOR technique for each one of them and got 0 in every case. That both answers it and handles my scenarios. Thanks!